# VBA - Creating array storing arrays

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to create an array storing arrays which stores 4 pieces of information. For example, region "0" is bound by 4 lines, x=1, x=2, y=3, y=4. I want to store the array like this " array[0]=(1,2,3,4)" Similarly, region "1" is bound by x=3, x= 6, y=2, y=3. I want to store the array like this "array[1]=(3,6,2,3)". I have tried to learn about jagged array. But I dont know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: What your looking for are multidimensional arrays, if you google "multi dimensional array vba" you get tons of informations. Here is one link: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Visual_Basic_Multidimensional_Arrays

Comment: @Doomenik Jagged arrays also apply.

Comment: My favorite VBA resource:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=28&t=7s)

Comment: @Doomenik Generally I don't like them as you can only `ReDim` last dimension.

Comment: thanks, I have used multidimensional arrays to solve my problems!

Answer (score 1):

```
data=Array(Array(1,2,3,4), Array(3,6,2,3), ...) 'This is your data
For region = 0 To 1
    debug.print "Region " & region & ":"
    debug.print "x=";data(region)(0)
    debug.print "x=";data(region)(1)
    debug.print "y";data(region)(2)
    debug.print "y=";data(region)(3)
Next
```